# Null check to an list before apply java steam to it

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a below code

```
item.getSubCategory().stream().map(category -> {
              return subCategoriesList.add(new SubCategoryViewModel(
                      category.get(String.format("_%s",categoryProperties[0])).toString(),
                      category.get(categoryProperties[2]).toString(),
                      category.get(categoryProperties[3]).toString()));
            }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The `item.getSubCategory()` is a list of category model. Now if null appears on the `getSubCategory` we get an null pointer exception and can't apply steam to it. Is there a better way to handle null check to the list before applying stream to it.

I don't want to use `IF` statement to check null on `getSubCategory`. Is there any better way in java steam API ?

Comment: `Optional.ofNullable(item.getSubCategory()).orElse(List.of()).stream()...`

Comment: Yes: fix getSubCategory to not return `null`.

Comment: …and by the way, `String.format("_%s",categoryProperties[0])` is a horribly expensive way to effectively do `"_" + categoryProperties[0]`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A method returning a list should never return `null` - it is a very bad practice. Just initialize the list in the constructor and return an empty one if there aren't any objects added to it. This way you eliminate all null checks that are needed whenever you want to use `getSubCategory`.

One could say that you end up with an unused object that takes memory. However, unless you have really a lot of `item` objects, having a few "spare" lists won't hurt anyone. Remember that code readability comes first in most cases - fix performance when you see actual problems.

Edit: as suggested by Holger, if you're worried about the memory cost of those empty lists, you could use `Collections.emptyList()`. Inside of your `item` you keep everything as it was, create the list only when it is needed and such. However, inside of `getSubCategory` instead of returning `null` you should check if the list is initialized and if it isn't then return `Collections.emptyList()` in place of null. According to documentation, `Collections.emptyList()` returns an immutable instance of a list, and multiple calls will return the same instance - only one will ever be created.

Comment: Even if you have a lot of `item` objects and fear the costs of an empty list, using `Collections.emptyList()` that returns a single shared object would solve this. But in Java 8 and later, an empty `ArrayList` created using the default constructor is very cheap either.

Comment: @Holger thanks for the comment, added that to my answer.

Comment: @Holger Just curious, why is it very cheap from Java 8 onwards?

Comment: @Lino because since Java 8, it will not allocate an array until you actually store elements into it. So the initial state is a lightweight object having three fields. Perhaps, that optimization is in Java 7 already, I’m not sure.

Comment: @Holger I see, I assumed there were some changes made to the escape analysis and I didn't even think about this simple lazy allocation. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Starting with Java 9, you can also make use of [`Objects.requireNonNullElse()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNullElse-T-T-):

```java
Objects.requireNonNullElse(item.getSubCategory(), Collections.emptyList())
    .stream()
    .map(...);
```

This may look similar to:

```java
Optional.ofNullable(item.getSubCategory()).orElse(Collections.emptyList())
    .stream()
    .map(...);
```

But it is different in the way, that `requireNonNullElse()` will directly return a non null `List`, while the `Optional` variant wraps the initial `List` in an `Optional` and is then unwrapped with `orElse()`

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a better way to handle null check to the list before
> applying stream to it.

Only one way I can think of. Make item `item.getSubCategory()` to return `Optional<YourObject>` instead of the actual object.

> I don't want to use IF statement to check null on getSubCategory. Is
> there any better way in java steam API ?

Your concern doesn't have to do with stream API. What you ask is how to treat an object that could be null, so that I don't have to use If, else checks.

Comment: Most of the times, optionals of list should not be used but instead the "empty" / "absent" return value should simply be an empty list instead.

Comment: Why return `Optional<List<Object>>` when you can just always return a empty `List<Object>`? It's always better to return something you can work with. If you can't return something to work with then return `Optional` or `null`.

Comment: @magicmn Because an empty list and absence of a list are two completely different results.

Comment: @ETO Yes of course, but a list should never be absent in the first place. You can have a empty list, but a missing list is bad practice...

Comment: @magicmn Please check my answer below. A comment doesn't seem enough for my explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this should be a good candidate for a comment, but I doubt one would be enough to explain my point.

---

I see very often people suggesting empty lists (or any empty collections) instead of `null`. In my view those are two completely different result types: **empty list** and **absent list**. Maybe sometimes an empty list is just fine, but that is not necessarily true in all the cases.

I agree that returning a `null` is a poor practice leading to lots of further issues. But `null` is not the only way of expressing absence of a result.
I'd rather use `Optional.empty()` instead of an empty list as a default result.

Here's an example demonstrating my point.

Let's assume we have a method fetching list of consumption records from an electricity meter. Sometimes the device might be offline, so you can't fetch anything and will retry later.
Now take a look at these two methods:

```
List<ConsumptionAmount> getConsumptionData(Date from, Date to);
```

```
Optional<List<ConsumptionAmount>> getConsumptionData(Date from, Date to);
```

---

The first implementation is very tricky. Returning empty list is very confusing (hence saying there was no energy consumption at all).

```
List<ConsumptionAmount> consumptionData = getConsumptionData(from, to);
// report 'zero consumption' to the billing service
```

Another option is to propagate an exception, which can also cause a `try-catch` mess in the code (The caller must be aware of the exception types and behave accordingly, otherwise the exception will be propagated further causing an even bigger mess):

```
try {
    List<ConsumptionAmount> consumptionData = getConsumptionData(from, to);
    // report consumption to the billing service
} catch (WhateverException ex) {
    // handle missing data here
}
```

---

The second implementation in contrast does not provide any details on the issue causing the absence of data, but it doesn't confuse the caller neither.

```
getConsumptionData(from, to).ifPresent( list -> /* report consumption here */);
```

If you do care of missing result, then simply provide another method ref:

```
getConsumptionData(from, to).ifPresentOrElse( 
    list -> /* report consumption here    */,
    ()   -> /* handle missing data here */
);
```

---

There are even more interesting functional approaches to such use cases (`Either` and `Try`), but unfortunately `Java` doesn't provide them out of the box. You can check third party frameworks like [this one](https://docs.vavr.io/#_either)

Comment: Good point, although this only applies when one has to differentiate between an empty list and an absent list. Many use cases just want to get a `List` of elements, and then iterate over said list to apply an action for each element. In that case it's better to return an empty `List` rather than a value indicating the `List` is absent

Comment: Going with your example of an electricity meter and the method `getConsumptionData`. I think you are building to much on the premise, that an absent value means the meter is offline. But returning `null` or `Optional.empty` has no meaning in itself, except for that there is no value. Maybe the device is offline, but it could also mean, that there is an error in the code and `null` is returned by mistake.

Comment: You already named one of the two  solutions I would prefer instead. Use an exception if the device is offline. The device could't be reached and thats very easy to express with a exception. Of course it doesn't look as fancy as using `Optional`, but it's more meaningful and less reliant on a good documentation.
My other prefered solution would be to wrap the whole respone in another object called `ElectricityMeterResponse` that could have a boolean `online` and additional methods like `ifOnline(Consumer<List> data)`. Of course it requires more effort to design an additional class.

Comment: @magicmn  "...less reliant on a good documentation..." , Well, in my opinion the `Optional` is less reliant on the documentation than the exceptions (especially the runtime ones). You express the possibility of an absent value by the type system and perform the safety checks at compile time.

Comment: @magicmn As for `ElectricityMeterResponse` solution you proposed, it is very good, actually. I can't say it is very different from returning an `Optional` or rather an `Either<YourException, YourResult>`. But the core idea is that returning an empty list may not suffice the requirements. So your solution is much better than a plain empty list.